# What version of Visual Studio is Python on my computer compiled with?

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio, visual-c++

I am trying to find out the version of Visual Studio that is used to compile the Python on my computer

It says

```
Python 2.6.2 (r262:71605, Apr 14 2009, 22:40:02) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
```

What I do not understand is this `MSC V.1500` designation. Does it mean it is compiled with Visual Studio 2005? I cannot find this information on http://python.org.

Comment: why would python be absolutely compiled with visual studio ? There are other compilers out there like gcc, etc...

Comment: @David Michel, The official distributions of Python are all compiled with Visual Studio.  He obviously didn't compile it himself (or he would know the answer).

Comment: Clearly, my version is compiled with MSC. I am sure the python on my linux is compiled with gcc. I need the compiler version because I have to compile python extension.

Comment: Does the release type, ie `release` or `debug` matter too? And how does one go about finding that out?

Comment: *I need the compiler version because I have to compile python extension.* See [What version of Visual Studio and/or MinGW do I need to build extension modules for a given version of Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12028762/95735)

Comment: How do you get that version string? All `python --version` is saying for me is `Python 2.7.8`-

Comment: Is there a clever way to get the information in Python in code?

Comment: Pretty much necro @poizan42, but I was looking for it and found out it with use of --help: `python -V -V' or 'python --version --version': -V     : print the Python version number and exit (also --version)
         when given twice, print more information about the build

Answer (score 186, accepted):

| Visual C++ version | _MSC_VER |
| --- | --- |
| Visual C++ 4.x | 1000 |
| Visual C++ 5 | 1100 |
| Visual C++ 6 | 1200 |
| Visual C++ .NET | 1300 |
| Visual C++ .NET 2003 | 1310 |
| Visual C++ 2005 (8.0) | 1400 |
| Visual C++ 2008 (9.0) | 1500 |
| Visual C++ 2010 (10.0) | 1600 |
| Visual C++ 2012 (11.0) | 1700 |
| Visual C++ 2013 (12.0) | 1800 |
| Visual C++ 2015 (14.0) | 1900 |
| Visual C++ 2017 (15.0) | 1910 |
| Visual C++ 2017 (15.3) | 1911 |
| Visual C++ 2017 (15.5) | 1912 |
| Visual C++ 2017 (15.6) | 1913 |
| Visual C++ 2017 (15.7) | 1914 |
| Visual C++ 2017 (15.8) | 1915 |
| Visual C++ 2017 (15.9) | 1916 |
| Visual C++ 2019 RTW (16.0) | 1920 |
| Visual C++ 2019 (16.1) | 1921 |
| Visual C++ 2019 (16.2) | 1922 |
| Visual C++ 2019 (16.3) | 1923 |
| Visual C++ 2019 (16.4) | 1924 |
| Visual C++ 2019 (16.5) | 1925 |
| Visual C++ 2019 (16.6) | 1926 |
| Visual C++ 2019 (16.7) | 1927 |
| Visual C++ 2019 (16.8) | 1928 |
| Visual C++ 2019 (16.9) | 1928 |
| Visual C++ 2019 (16.10) | 1929 |
| Visual C++ 2019 (16.11) | 1929 |
| Visual Studio 2022 RTW (17.0) | 1930 |

Source: the documentation for the [`_MSC_VER`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/predefined-macros) predefined macro

Comment: such a crap way of indicating the version ! how to make things obscure, lesson 1! Thanks this though Drorhan, it's definitely a "nice to know"!

Comment: A little longer list is given in [Detecting compiler versions during compile time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3592805/)

Comment: Where does this table come from?

Comment: Where did the info for 2010 and 2012 come from?

Comment: @CraigMcQueen here is a detailed list http://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/Compilers/

Comment: Hi. python 3.7 uses `MSC v.1912 64 bit (AMD64)`. what version is this?? can you please update!

Answer (score 13):

`MSC v.1500` appears to be Visual C++ 2008 according to [this thread on the OpenCobol forums](http://www.opencobol.org/modules/newbb/viewtopic.php?topic_id=743&forum=1) (of all places).

The [MSDN page on Predefined Macros](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay.aspx) indicates 1500 to be the result of the `_MSC_VER` macro.

[This other forum post](http://www.nr.com/forum/showthread.php?t=1459) mentions that

> (For reference, Visual Studio 2003 has `_MSC_VER` = 1310; Visual Studio 2005 has `_MSC_VER` = 1400; Visual Studio 2008 has `_MSC_VER` = 1500.)

The above MSDN link said that 1600 indicates VS2010.

Strangely, I wasn't able to find that info about the earlier `_MSC_VER` values on MSDN.

Comment: Not the first day that M$ makes programmer life harder. This is why we are a better man now.

Comment: Hi. `python 3.7` uses `MSC v.1912 64 bit (AMD64)`. what version is this?? can you please update!

Comment: @KhalilAlHooti, I'm not completely certain, but v.1912 is probably Visual Studio 2018. Perhaps download the community edition and double check.

Comment: @KhalilAlHooti, `1912` is __Visual C++ 2017 (15.5)__. See the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2676904/12892).