# Ipython default directory

Tags: python, windows-7, ipython

I am installing ipython in my windows machine.

I add the path C:\python34\scripts\ and ran this command

```
    pip install ipython
```

Once it is completed, ipython.exe is found in C:\python34\scripts\
and when i try this statement

```
    m = array([arange(2), arange(2)])
```

it returns NameError: name 'array' is not defined

Question
1. is C:\python34\scripts\ the correct directory to install to?
2. if yes, do i need to import library everything i run
3. if not, which directory should i install and how to install

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Ipython](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPython) is just an interactive command shell which somehow extends the normal Python shell to become more interactive and does not, generally speaking, include any additional Python modules or packages.

[`array`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) and [`arange`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) are part of the [`numpy`](http://www.numpy.org/) package which needs to be installed additionally by executing

```
pip install numpy
```

However, working on Windows `numpy` requires Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28414059/3991125).

So, first of all, you should make sure to have Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 installed and afterwards you should be able to install `numpy` using `pip`.

After `numpy` works as desired you need to import this module in order to use it as desired:

```
from numpy import array, arange
m = array([arange(2), arange(2)])
```

For a more general approach I would suggest the following:

```
import numpy as np
m = np.array([np.arange(2), np.arange(2)])
```