# How do I install numpy for Python 3.5 on Windows?

Tags: python, numpy, python-3.5

I can import numpy in the shell and in the IDLE but when I run the project the drop an error that says "module numpy has no attribute array" and I don't know how to solve this.

Comment: Please give more details: which IDLE, which shell, which OS, where your script is executed from, etc.

Comment: The default idle and shell from the python page, my OS is windows

Comment: https://www.python.org/downloads/

Comment: OK just checking your note on an on-line interpreter. So you can run the script from the IDLE but not from the command line ?

Comment: What's the name of the files in the project? Is there a numpy.py by any chance?

Comment: Check this instructions how to install nupy the right way: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28414059/524743