# Python: Incorrect Intellisense autocompletion for numpy

Tags: python, visual-studio, autocomplete, intellisense

One thing I can't get over - when I use numpy in Visual Studio and I want to declare an array of zeroes, I write:

`x = numpy.zeros(n)`

and it is correct for the interpreter. BUT THE AUTOCOMPLETION GIVES ME:

`X = numpy.zeros_like ...`

How can I change it to get actually helpful autocompletion? In C++ I get everything allright, so I guess it's an internal problem in Python case.

Edit: As I see the problem is that numpy.zeros is defined in numeric.py as:
`zeros = multiarray.zeros`. Apparently this is not enough for IntelliSense (or VisualAssist for this matter), which requires `def function` to actually see the structure.

Comment: Have you tried vscode with the Python module? It really is **the perfect editor**, seriously. The auto-completion and the linter are just precious ;)

Comment: I'll check that, thanks for the hint :)

Comment: @Ch3shire, what's the python version does you installed and does your issue is solved or not?

Comment: @Sara-MSFT i have both 3.4 and 2.7 (but I use 2.7), as far as I know Visual Studio interprets for 2.7.

Comment: @Ch3shire, does your issue is solved or not?

Comment: Not quite, I don't have working solution. For now I just write in Visual Studio Code where I have less intrusive autocompletion. I'll try to apply your solution later, for now I'll mark your answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the [python 3.5](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-350/) and download the corresponding wheel for [numpy](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy). Then using the command: pip install xxxx(numpy wheel version that you download) to install it. For more the detail information about the installation staff, you can have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28413824/installing-numpy-on-windows).

Then open or create a python application project in VS and set the python 3.5 as the default environment, then I can found the intellisense for numpy.zeros also works fine in .py file like the following screenshot: (python 3.5)
[image]

If set the python 2.7 as the default environment, the intellisense just like your description as below:
[image]

Comment: It's weird but I can't get same result. Thanks for help though :)

Comment: @Ch3shire, you already used the python 3.5 as the default environment? If not, you can have a try with install and configure it.