# Compiling Python modules on Windows x64

Tags: python, visual-studio, python-2.7, compilation, windows-7-x64

I'm starting out some projects in words processing and I needed NumPy and NLTK.
That was the first time I got to know `easy_install` and how to compile new module of python into the system.

I have Python 2.7 x64 plus VS 11 and VS 12. Also Cygwin (the latest one I guess).
I could see in the file that compiles using VS that it looks for VS env with the same version as the one that compiled the python code, why?
When I hardcoded 11.0 which is my version, numpy failed to build on several strange errors regarding `vcvarsall` (it found `vcvarsall`, probably misused it).

Can't I build python binaries on Windows?
If not, can I cross compile on Linux for Windows? (using the same method as Google for the Android SDK)

Comment: Building binary extensions on Windows is notoriously difficult. Sadly the [Python Packaging User Guide](http://python-packaging-user-guide.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) is incomplete [on this subject](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/extensions/#building-binary-extensions). Contributions welcome.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817869/error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

***Update:** This answer is now over 5 years old! Python-2.7 is about to be deprecated, so what you really need is a Microsoft Visual C compiler for Python-3. Take a look at [this Python wiki on MS Windows Compilers](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers). MS Build Tools 2015 with VC-14.0 is what you need to build extensions for Python-3.5 and 3.6. You can either install the older [MS build tools 2015](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48159) which includes VC-14.0 or the newer [MS build tools for 2017](http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools) - click the link, then scroll down until you find [Build Tools for Visual Studio 2017](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2017) - which also includes VC-14.0.*

*Also if your versions of pip and setuptools are up to date, then you can ignore all of that silly old school MSSDK nonsense. Especially if you are using the VC for Python 2.7 or MS build tools 2015. Since setuptools-24, it just knows where to look for these compilers, hopefully.*

***Update:** As [Zooba](https://stackoverflow.com/users/891/zooba) mentions below, [free x86 and AMD64 (x86-64) VC90 c-compilers for Python-2.7 are now available from Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44266).*

***Update:** [Patch `vcvarsall.bat`](https://gist.github.com/mikofski/11024332#file-vcvarsall-bat-patch) to use x64 compilers from SDK v7.0 directly with `pip` in any shell instead of using SDK shell and setting `DISTUTILS_USE_SDK` and `MSSdk` environmental variables as in directions below. See [Fix vcvarsall.bat to install Python-2.7 x64 extensions with v90 instead of sdk7](http://poquitopicante.blogspot.com/2014/04/fix-vcvarsallbat-to-install-python-27.html).*

***tl;dr:** Use Windows SDK v7.0 compilers, open the SDK shell and call*

```
C:\> setenv /release /x64
C:\> set DISTUTILS_USE_SDK=1
C:\> MSSdk=1
```

*to build Python 2.7.x extensions using distutils, `pip` or `easy_install`. See [Python x64 Package Extensions with pip, MSVC 2008 Express & SDK 7](http://poquitopicante.blogspot.com/2012/11/python-x64-package-extensions-with-pip.html).*

*Note*: You can install [Numpy optimized using Intel MKL from Christoph Gohlke](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy). For virtualenv's, try converting the binary distribution windows installer to a [wheel](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wheel) file which can be installed with pip. Building [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/) from source is **not** trivial. It has become a possibility with the recent introduction and availability of [OpenBLAS](http://www.openblas.net/), a fork of [GotoBLAS](http://www.tacc.utexas.edu/tacc-projects/gotoblas2). There are [optimized binaries available for Windows x86 and x86-64](http://sourceforge.net/projects/openblas/files) as well as source which is relatively simpler to compile than GotoBLAS or [ATLAS](http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/).

*Note*: In the past I hadn't recommended compiling NumPy from source because you had to optimize BLAS for your platform which was very time-intensive, and the reference BLAS (FORTRAN) or CBLAS (C/C++) implementations were relatively low-performing. Also NumPy depends on [LAPACK](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) which also depends on BLAS an additional hurdle to building NumPy. However OpenBLAS binaries are already compiled with LAPACK, so this obstacle has already been removed. See [Carl Kleffner's static MinGW-w64 toolchains to build NumPy with OpenBLAS on Windows](https://bitbucket.org/carlkl/mingw-w64-for-python) - he has resolved some of the ABI incompatibilities and issues linking to the correct Microsoft Visual C Common Runtime library (`msvcr90.dll` for Python-2.7).

## So onward to the main question about installing Python extensions on Windows 7 x64.

The recommended way to compile extensions is to use the same compiler used to compile the Python shared library [1-3]. The [official Python 2.7.x for Windows](http://www.python.org/getit/) was compiled using [Microsoft Visual C++ Compilers version 9.0 [4] (aka MSVC90 or simply VC90) from Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3713), which you might be able to get for free from [Microsoft DreamSpark](https://www.dreamspark.com/Product/Product.aspx?productid=1). Evidentally the x64 compilers are not installed by default, so make sure they are installed along with the x86 compilers. *Note: MS Visual Studio 2008 may no longer be available, but MS Visual Studio 2010 will let you use the MSVC90 toolchain if installed, which can be installed from Windows SDK7.*

You can tell what version your Python was built with by looking at the header when you execute the python interpreter from a command line. *e.g.*: `Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 23:24:47) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32` means that it was built with VS 2008 C++. You can build Python yourself from source, but this is also an arduous task. In general it is not recommended to mix compiler runtimes, although in practice you may find that they still work.

If you have your heart set on using [GNU GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), then you would have to use [mingw-w64](http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/) because [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) is only for native x86 applications, not AMD64/x86-64. You will need to

- [create a distutils config file to specify the mingw compiler](http://docs.python.org/2/install/index.html?highlight=pydistutils#distutils-configuration-files),
- [remove the -mno-cygwin bug from distutils.cygwinccompiler.Mingw32ccompiler](http://bugs.python.org/issue12641) and
- [export a library definitions file using either `pexports.exe` from msys or `gendef.exe` from msys2 and make a static library `libpython27.a` using `dlltool.exe` (msys/msys2) (but the newest releases of Official Python for Windows already have this file in the `Python27\lib` folder, thanks!)](https://docs.python.org/2/install/index.html?highlight=pexports#older-versions-of-python-and-mingw).

However in the end you will *still* need to link against the runtime that python was built with, `msvcr90.dll`, so you will need [Visual C++ 2008 redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/search.aspx?q=Visual+C%2b%2b+2008+redistributable). *Note: Windows GCC from mingw-w64 uses [`msvcrt.dll` which is not the same as `msvcr90.dll` or later](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows_library_files#MSVCRT.DLL_and_MSVCPP.DLL).*

If you want to do it for free you can use [Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Express SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14597) but you will need to add the [Windows SDK 7 for .NET Frameworks 3.5 SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3138) because the express version does **not** have the x64 compilers. The procedure for installing x64 C++ extensions with VS2008 Express  & SDK 7 are very similar to the those on the [cython site for windows x64 extensions](http://wiki.cython.org/64BitCythonExtensionsOnWindows). *Note: MS Visual Studio 2008 Express is no longer available or supported.*

FYI: You do not necessarily need Visual Studio to build using Microsoft compilers. They are available free with the appropriate SDK package. `CL.EXE` is the compiler executable, but you will have to set whatever platform options that are normally configured by Autotools or some other tool such as CMAKE. CMAKE plays well with MSVC, but Autotools AFAIK doesn't work with MSVC and would require some POSIX environment and utilities which on Windows are available in [MSYS](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/External%20binary%20packages%20%28Win64%20hosted%29/MSYS%20%2832-bit%29/).

For many Python packages that use distutils or setuptools, they can compile extensions using Windows SDK 7 by following the directions that are posted in various places through the reference documentation and wikis:

1. From the **Start Menu** select **All Programs** then **Microsoft Windows SDK v7.0** and start **CMD Shell** to open a command window optimized for Windows SDK.
2. Step #1 is the equivalent of typing the following in the **Run** box from the **Start Menu** or from a Command Prompt (aka `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe`):

   ```
   %COMSPEC% /E:ON /V:ON /K "%PROGRAMFILES%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Bin\SetEnv.cmd"
   ```

   NOTE: The flags `/E:ON`, which enables command extensions, and `/V:ON`, which enables delayed variable expansion, are both necessary to for `SetEnv.cmd` to function, or you will get an message that the x64 compilers are not installed, &c.
3. Then type `setenv /Release /x64` which will set the SDK environment variables specifically for Windows 7 x64 release (vs debug or x86 which are the default).
4. Type `set DISTUTILS_USE_SDK=1` hit return and then type `set MSSdk=1` and return to tell `distutils.msvccompiler` that you are using the SDK, and that the SDK will determine all of the environment variables.
5. Now use your installation method of choice:

   - `pip install pyyaml ntlk` which is the recommended way, [see ntlk](http://nltk.org/install.html), but you must have [setuptools](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools) and [pip](http://www.pip-installer.org) installed.
   - `python setup.py install` for each downloaded, extracted tarball
   - `easy_install pyyaml ntlk` which is the old way and the only way to install eggs.

[1] [Building C and C++ Extensions on Windows](http://docs.python.org/2/extending/windows.html)
[2] [distutils.msvccompiler — Microsoft Compiler](http://docs.python.org/2/distutils/apiref.html#module-distutils.msvccompiler)
[3] [Python Dev Guide: Getting Started: Windows](http://docs.python.org/devguide/setup.html#windows)
[4] [What version of visual studio is this python compiled with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2676763/what-version-of-visual-studio-is-this-python-compiled-with)

Comment: If you want to build extensions for Python 2.7-3.2, the compiler package at http://aka.ms/vcpython27 and setuptools 6.0 or later are now the easiest options.

Comment: Sorry to comment and then post my own answer :( Feel free to update your answer - I care more about people hearing about the fixes than getting the up votes.

Answer (score 13):

Since the other answers, Microsoft has released a compiler package specifically for building extensions for Python 2.7 (and any version of Python that used VS 2008/VC9). Here's how to use it:

1. Go to http://aka.ms/vcpython27, download and install the package (it's fairly small and does not require administrator rights)
2. Update setuptools to 6.0 or later (`pip install -U setuptools`)
3. Install your package (`pip install <whatever>`)

The combination of the latest setuptools version and this compiler pack should make it really easy to do this.

Comment: Thanks for updating this with the new [Microsoft Visual C++ Compilers for Python 2.7](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44266)! I had already updated the blog post this points to, but I hadn't updated this answer yet.

Answer (score 0):

there are several ways to do it apparently.

1. build using mingw
2. build python 2.7 using VS 2008 express.
3. i'm not sure regarding which version is good to build 3.2 but it could be VS 2010.
4. you can compile python x64 from source using your desired VS, but u'll have competability issues with other pre built packages.

Answer (score 0):

This worked best for me:

1. Install `Visual Studio Express 2008`
2. Install `Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .NET Framework 3.5 SP1` from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3138
3. Go to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\bin` and open the `Visual Studio 2008 x64 Win64 Command Prompt`
4. In that shell, run `pip install <package>`

You should not have to install any redistributable packages on client systems when done this way.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows 10, Python 2.7.11, Cygwin 2.5.2 and x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc 4.9.2
or 5.4.0 (but see **note** under 1 below), pulling together comments from elsewhere, here's what I had to do for my Python extension to compile, link, and beat a race condition between msvcrt.dll and msvcr90.dll:

1. Edit distutils/cygwinccompiler, and in `class Mingw32CCompiler`

   - Replace the old -mno-cygwin fix with

     ```
     if self.gcc_version < '4' or is_cygwingcc():
       no_cygwin = ' -nostdlib -lgcc'
     ```

     for gcc 4.9.2 -- **note** for 5.4.0, no 'if', just

     ```
     no_cygwin = ''
     ```
   - Get the right compiler in place:

     ```
             self.set_executables(compiler='x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc%s -O -Wall' % no_cygwin,
                      compiler_so='x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc%s -mdll -O -Wall' % no_cygwin,
                      compiler_cxx='x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++%s -O -Wall' % no_cygwin,
                      linker_exe='x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc%s' % no_cygwin,
                      linker_so='x86_64-w64-mingw32-%s%s %s %s'
     ```
   - **note** for x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc 5.4.0, it seems to work better *without* msvcr90, so make the call to `get_msvcr` conditional:

     ```
             if self.gcc_version < '5':
                 self.dll_libraries = get_msvcr()
     ```
2. Use a setup.py with the following

   ```
   libdirs=['C:\\Python27\\libs',...]
   macros=[('MS_WIN64','1'),...]
   platform="WIN32"
   ```
3. Patch one of my source file headers to include

   ```
   #ifdef MS_WIN64
   #define strdup _strdup
   #endif
   ```
4. Finally,

   ```
    /c/Python27/python [editted setup].py -v build --compiler=mingw32
    /c/Python27/python [editted setup].py -v install
   ```

Some of the above may not be in quite the optimal place, but it got my extension working...