# Does `pip install` respect the compiler version used to build Python?

Tags: python, pip, python-extensions

Does `pip install` always build extension modules with the same compiler that was used to compile the current Python version?

For example, [this blog post](https://jurajtomori.wordpress.com/2018/11/28/nuke-tip-installing-numpy-for-nuke-python-on-windows/) explained that `numpy` package uses C code, which has to be compiled against the same compiler as the Python itself:

> Python 2.7.13 (default, Aug 21 2017, 11:46:40) [**MSC v.1900** 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

tells us which compiler was used. `numpy` and other packages have to be compiled against that identical version.

Comment: Python is not a compiled language. Are you talking about the interpreter?

Comment: It depends on how you have installed pip. While installing pip if you have used python2.7 then pip will install packages corresponding to the said version of python

Comment: I added some sample information.

Answer (score 1):

`pip install` never installs a compiler. You have to have the compiler before running `pip install`.

See https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers to learn what version of VC you need to install for different versions of Python.

It would be much simpler to install a precompiled wheel. Said numpy has [a lot of precompiled wheels](https://pypi.org/project/numpy/#files). Currently there are binary wheels for Python 2.7, 3.5, 3.6 and 3.7 on MacOS 64 bits, Linux 32 and 64 bits, Windows 32 and 64 bits. Just type `pip install numpy` and your `pip` automatically determines what platform it's being ran on and download and install the proper wheel.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes!** Originally `pip` was built on top of `distutils` package [which by default enforces](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.11.0/Lib/distutils/ccompiler.py#L918-L956) extension modules to be compiled with [the same compiler](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.11.0/Lib/distutils/ccompiler.py#L918-L956) as an interpreter itself. Currently it mostly installs packages from pre-built wheels (which in turn are also built with help of `distutils`) and packages still have to use `setuptools` to be able to build extension modules.

On Windows com­piler ver­sion is also [enforced to be the same](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.11.0/Lib/distutils/msvc9compiler.py#L166-L190) (or, since Python 3.5, [compatible](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.11.0/Lib/distutils/_msvccompiler.py#L94-L111)). On Unix-likes [the compiler and linker flags](https://docs.python.org/3.11/install/index.html#building-extensions-tips-and-tricks) used to compile Python [will also be used](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.11.0/Lib/distutils/sysconfig.py#L192-L261) to compile extensions.

---

Note that this is more of a convenience and safeguard rather than a requirement. [Except for some special cases](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54811953/11725753) Python exten­sions should work just fine when built with another compiler version.

Answer (score 0):

Pip prioritises the version on your PATH. Pip3 and Pip are used to differentiate between the two versions.

https://docs.python.org/2/installing/index.html

Comment: This doesn't regard the question I asked