# Failed to build ta-lib ERROR: Could not build wheels for ta-lib, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based project

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, algorithmic-trading, technical-indicator

I'm getting below error, while pip installing ta-lib.
I used command :

```
!pip install ta-lib
```

Please provide me solution.

```
    Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://us-python.pkg.dev/colab-wheels/public/simple/
Collecting ta-lib
  Using cached TA-Lib-0.4.25.tar.gz (271 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from ta-lib) (1.21.6)
Building wheels for collected packages: ta-lib
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Building wheel for ta-lib (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> See above for output.
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  Building wheel for ta-lib (pyproject.toml) ... error
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for ta-lib
Failed to build ta-lib
ERROR: Could not build wheels for ta-lib, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I tried following commands :

```
pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
```

```
pip install pep517
```

```
!pip3 install --upgrade pip
```

```
!pip install pyproject-toml
```

```
pip install TA_Lib‑0.4.10‑cp35‑cp35m‑win_amd64.whl
```

```
!pip install ta-lib
```

Comment: I have the same problem while installing [`gtar`](https://pypi.org/project/gtar/), which suggests to install Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater. It still does not work after installation of MVC++ 17.4.5.

Answer (score 14):

Typing the following command in the Anaconda Command Prompt (exactly like this) fixed it for me:

```
conda install -c conda-forge ta-lib
```

Hopefully this will save others' time as well.

Comment: I was getting:   
   ERROR: Failed building wheel for Ta-lib
   Failed to build Ta-lib
   ERROR: Could not build wheels for Ta-lib, which is required to install 
   pyproject.toml-based projects
but the above : conda install -c conda-forge ta-lib
solved it. Make sure you do it in the conda terminal

Comment: This command works on my macOS 12.6.8

Answer (score 11):

In Ubuntu 22.04 I solved this issue by following these steps below;

(BTW it is also mentioned in the official page [here](https://pypi.org/project/TA-Lib/) )

1. Download [ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz](http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/ta-lib/ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz) and put it to the directory where you are planning to install talib, lets' say **"~/talib"**
   open bash and skip to the directory that you just put the downloaded file `cd ~/talib`
   and;
2. `tar -xzf ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz`
3. `cd ta-lib/`
4. `./configure --prefix=/usr`
5. `make`
6. `sudo make install`
7. add necessary directories to the path.
   To do that;

Edit .bashrc in your home directory and add the following line:
please remember to change **PREFIX** with your path to talib
*(~/talib/ta-lib/)*

> export TA_LIBRARY_PATH=$**PREFIX**/lib

> export TA_INCLUDE_PATH=$**PREFIX**/include

8. `pip install TA-Lib`

Then it was installed successfully.
Good luck!

Comment: This works but some attention has to be paid when you do not have access to /usr or try to install it in an environment.

Answer (score 9):

Solved on mac executing on a terminal:

```bash
$ brew install ta-lib
```

Comment: This worked for me on ubuntu (wsl), had to restart the terminal session

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways, try the following first, It works on Google Colab:

```
!curl -L http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/ta-lib/ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz -O && tar xzvf ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz

!cd ta-lib && ./configure --prefix=/usr && make && make install && cd - && pip install ta-lib
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much, for me it worked with your answer then i had to restart the session.

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs because the wheel file for TA-Lib is not compatible with your system. The wheel file is a pre-built version of the library that is specific to a certain version of Python and a certain operating system architecture (e.g., Windows, Linux, macOS).

There are a couple of things you can try to solve this error:

Make sure that you have the correct version of Python installed on your system. The wheel file for TA-Lib that you are trying to install is for Python 3.10, so you need to have that version of Python installed in order to use it.

Check if the wheel file you are trying to install is for the correct architecture (e.g., win_amd64 for Windows 64-bit).

You can try to build the wheel from the source code. You can try to download the source code from TA-Lib website and then try to build it from source. It will make sure you will have wheel file of that version of python and the operating system architecture.

Alternatively, you can try installing the library using pip without using the wheel file by using command : pip install TA-Lib

Or you can look for another wheel file of TA-Lib that matches your system architecture and Python version.

By trying any of the above solutions you should be able to successfully install the TA-Lib library.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to install the correct version:

cp310 means CPython 3.10 (Cpython is the basic Python that we install from python.org) .

win_amd64 means can be installed in Systems with 64 bits

cp39 means it can be installed on CPython 3.9

And so on ...

Check to install the correct version. It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

### Short answer

It requires right compiler with your system to build `ta-lib` python package, since [`pip install` never installs a compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55222258/9475509).

### Long answer

I do not now whether it is related or not since I have similar problem while installing [`gtar`](https://pypi.org/project/gtar/). I include only similar error messages.

```
[..]
Building wheels for collected packages: gtar
  Building wheel for gtar (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Building wheel for gtar (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [15 lines of output]
[..]
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for gtar
Failed to build gtar
ERROR: Could not build wheels for gtar, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

After install Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater as suggested, in my case is **Desktop development with C++** (including MVSC v143) using [Visual Studio Build Tools 2022 -- 17.4.5](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/), it builds sucessfully as follow.

```
[..
Building wheels for collected packages: gtar
  Building wheel for gtar (pyproject.toml) ... done
  Created wheel for gtar: filename=gtar-1.1.3-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl size=618949 sha256=3179a7e8b5deb7e72f5722acc08fbecdfec6eeab88c4ac5778d3287a45635086
  Stored in directory: c:\users\full name\appdata\local\pip\cache\wheels\8a\10\b1\eddc3353608cbc386b0113f2bea34c83e5fae7ce26deb059db
Successfully built gtar
Installing collected packages: gtar
Successfully installed gtar-1.1.3
```

Answer (score 0):

I had issues on Mac Big Sur until I reinstalled command line tools and updated clang ...

```
% sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
% sudo xcode-select --install
% clang --version
Apple clang version 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.11)

THEN...
$ pip3 install ta-lib
Collecting ta-lib
  Using cached TA-Lib-0.4.25.tar.gz (271 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from ta-lib) (1.24.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: ta-lib
  Building wheel for ta-lib (pyproject.toml) ... done
  Created wheel for ta-lib: filename=TA_Lib-0.4.25-cp310-cp310-macosx_11_0_x86_64.whl size=450718 sha256=d793bcd939d8b4c43efa00359ae45207e18d5d622a3d794f8da1fef12279d23b
  Stored in directory: /Users/xxxxxx/Library/Caches/pip/wheels/ac/12/d0/2ea05cfb5b9c4bbf47b45dd93ff5baed86ddb85c748166cb6f
Successfully built ta-lib
Installing collected packages: ta-lib
Successfully installed ta-lib-0.4.25
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting a similar error, but with another line `ta-lib/ta_defs.h: No such file or directory`, and I just used `python3 -m pip install TA-Lib-Precompiled`, and that worked for me.