Problems installing TA-Lib to use in PyCharm on Ubuntu 22.04
I have been around the houses many times with this issue. Ultimately I am trying to get TA-Lib imported into my PyCharm IDE, but so far without success. My setup is as follows:
Ubuntu 22.04,
Python 3.10.12,
PyCharm 2024.1 Communuity Edition
It would appear that getting TA-Lib installed can be challenging to say the least looking at all the various posts. I won't go through everything I have done (largely because I can't remember), but the latest post I have used is: this, in particular I have done the following steps:
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y && sudo apt autoremove -y
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa -y
wget http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/ta-lib/ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz
tar -xzf ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz
cd ta-lib
wget 'http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=config.git;a=blob_plain;f=config.guess;hb=HEAD' -O './config.guess'
wget 'http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=config.git;a=blob_plain;f=config.sub;hb=HEAD' -O './config.sub'
./configure --prefix=/usr
make
sudo make install
sudo rm -rf ta-lib
sudo rm -rf ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz
pip install ta-lib

Before the above I did my best to remove all traces of previous attempts at installing TA-Lib, and I didn't notice any errors when carrying out the above.
I then go to PyCharm -> Settings -> Project:[My Project] -> Python Interpreter, and then under Packages I add a Package by clicking on the '+' sign, I search for 'TA-Lib', I select TA-Lib, then click Install Package. After a few seconds I get an error:
Collecting TA-Lib
  Using cached TA-Lib-0.4.28.tar.gz (357 kB)
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
  Getting requirements to build wheel: started
  Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
  Installing backend dependencies: started
  Installing backend dependencies: finished with status 'done'
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in ./Projects/Python/Env/lib/python3.12/site-packages (from TA-Lib) (1.26.4)
Building wheels for collected packages: TA-Lib
  Building wheel for TA-Lib (pyproject.toml): started
  Building wheel for TA-Lib (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
Failed to build TA-Lib

  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Building wheel for TA-Lib (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [20 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-312
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-312/talib
      copying talib/deprecated.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-312/talib
      copying talib/stream.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-312/talib
      copying talib/abstract.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-312/talib
      copying talib/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-312/talib
      running build_ext
      building 'talib._ta_lib' extension
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-312
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-312/talib
      x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -fno-strict-overflow -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -I/opt/include -I/opt/local/include -I/opt/homebrew/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/ta-lib/include -I/tmp/pip-build-env-__jc6xx4/normal/lib/python3.12/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/data/stuart/Projects/Python/Env/include -I/usr/include/python3.12 -c talib/_ta_lib.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-312/talib/_ta_lib.o
      talib/_ta_lib.c:16:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
         16 | #include "Python.h"
            |          ^~~~~~~~~~
      compilation terminated.
      error: command '/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for TA-Lib
ERROR: Could not build wheels for TA-Lib, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

I get similar errors if I try:
pip install ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz

which is an answer I found in another thread.
I have spent 2 days trying to resolve this issue, so far to no avail. Any help would be much appreciated.
Regards, Stuart

check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74651107/error-could-not-build-wheels-for-ta-lib-which-is-required-to-install-pyproject

It happens happens because talib is mainly written in c and python library is only wrapper arround it's c library.
To install TaLib on a Linux system, follow these steps::

Download the TaLib source gz file from here

Open the terminal and navigate to the directory where the gz file is downloaded.

Run the following commands:.
tar -xzf ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz
cd ta-lib/
./configure --prefix=/usr
make
sudo make install
pip3 install TA-Lib


For More details you can refer this

Thanks Harshid Patel. Unfortunately the results were the same. The only difference in procedure is that I originally used pip rather than pip3. I used pip3 this time. The installation appeared to be error free. Problems arise when I try to import TA-Lib into PyCharm with Settings -> Project: [My Project] -> Python Interpreter, as per my OP. Any further help would be much appreciated. Regards, StuartM

Try running following commands to add python dependencies
sudo apt-get install python3.10-dev libsasl2-dev python-dev-is-python3 libldap2-dev libssl-dev
