ValueError: numpy.dtype size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility while importing `TA-Lib`
Was having trouble with installing TA-Lib 0.4.32 on my machine with the following specs:
OS: POP-OS 22.04
Python: 3.10.20
Pip: 22.0.2

Doing 'pip install TA-Lib==0.4.32` directly gives out the following error:
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for TA-Lib
Failed to build TA-Lib


I found a solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/75311818/13520498 to install correctly. I followed through it and was able to install it without any issue.
But now when I try to import the library it gives out following error:
import talib as ta

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/arrafi/faraz_new/ta_feature.py", line 1, in <module>
    import talib as ta
  File "/home/arrafi/faraz_new/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/talib/__init__.py", line 93, in <module>
    from ._ta_lib import (
  File "talib/_ta_lib.pyx", line 1, in init talib._ta_lib
ValueError: numpy.dtype size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 96 from C header, got 88 from PyObject

