# How can I build a setup.py to compile C++ extension using Python, pybind11 and Mingw-w64?

Tags: python, c++, mingw-w64, distutils, pybind11

I'm currently trying to write a 'setup.py' script that when the user installs the python package automatically compiles my C++ extension bound with 'pybind11'. In Windows, I haven't got any problem making it happen with the 'VS19 MSVC' compiler. But I'm trying to make it happen if the user has installed 'MinGW-w64' instead.

These are the package files:

```
**main.cpp**

    #include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
    
    int add(int i, int j) {
        return i + j;
    }
    
    namespace py = pybind11;
    
    PYBIND11_MODULE(pybind11_example, m) {
    
        m.def("add", &add);
    }
```

```py
**setup.py**

    from setuptools import setup, Extension
    import pybind11
    
    ext_modules = [
        Extension(
            'pybind11_example',
            sources = ['main.cpp'],
            include_dirs=[pybind11.get_include()],
            language='c++'
        ),
    ]
    
    setup(
        name='pybind11_example',
        ext_modules=ext_modules
    )
```

Having the two files in the same folder and running from the command prompt:

```sh
    python setup.py build
```

If the user has `VS19 MSVC` compiler installed it successfully generates `**pybind11_example.pyd**` that can be tested to work running with python:

```py
    import pybind11_example as m
    print(m.add(1, 2))
```

But if the user has a `Mingw-w64` compiler installed raises an error saying that Visual Studio 2015 is required.

Note that I can easily compile `**main.cpp**` in to `**pybind11_example.pyd**` manually with `Mingw-w64` running:

```
    g++ -static -shared -std=c++11 -DMS_WIN64 -fPIC -I C:\...\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\pybind11\include -I C:\ ... \Python\Python38\include -L C:\ ... \Python\Python38\libs main.cpp -o pybind11_example.pyd -lPython38
```

Is there a way to write `**setup.py**` in a way that if the user has Windows with a `MinGW-w64` compiler automatically compile `**main.cpp**` into `**pybind11_example.pyd**` when installing the package without needing to make it manually?

Comment: Chek the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33331563/force-compiler-when-running-python-setup-py-install). They try to solve the opposite case, force msvc instead of mingw, but the approach with `setup.cfg` might help you.

Comment: And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724664/python-distutils-how-to-get-a-compiler-that-is-going-to-be-used) the answer demonstrates how to specify command line parameters depending on the choice made by setup tools: if it is `msvc` then one set of parameters, and another set for `mingw`

Answer (score 2):

Chek the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33331563/force-compiler-when-running-python-setup-py-install). They try to solve the opposite case, force msvc instead of mingw, but the approach with setup.cfg might help you.

And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724664/python-distutils-how-to-get-a-compiler-that-is-going-to-be-used) the answer demonstrates how to specify command line parameters depending on the choice made by setup tools: if it is msvc then one set of parameters, and another set for mingw.

I belive the second approach should suite your needs - whichever compier is installled, you have the proper command line to build your module.