# What does the Python version line mean?

Tags: python, 32bit-64bit

What does the line that's displayed when you start an instance of the Python interpreter mean?

```
Python 2.7 (r27:82525, Jul  4 2010, 07:43:08) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
```

So I know I have Python 2.7, but what about the rest?

Especially confusing to me are the `64 bit (AMD64) on win32` and `r27:82525` sections.

Comment: For reference, here's the [current start text for Python2 & Python3 on Arch Linux](http://pastebin.com/y053y6dT).

Comment: How do you get that version string? All `python --version` is saying for me is `Python 2.7.8`

Comment: @poizan42 It appears when you enter python shell. In the command line when you just type python, this text appears right before the line which asks for your input `>>>`

Comment: You're right, I'm feeling stupid now

Answer (score 46, accepted):

That line you see indicates how the python interpreter was built. Breaking it down:

```
Python 2.7                        -- Python version
(r27:82525, Jul 4 2010, 07:43:08) -- The build date and revision from src trunk 
                                     that was used to build this.
[MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]       -- Compiled with MSVC compiler targeting 64-bit
on win32                          -- All Windows platforms (64- and 32-bit)
```

Comment: But why wouldn't it say win64?

Comment: @Mark It's mainly due to historical reasons. `win32` is a bit of a misnomer since it's generally used to refer to windows platform regardless of bit width support.

Comment: @JonKiparsky You may be making a joke, but just in case - Windows has "win" as the first three letters

Comment: @Mark Don't you mean [WoW64](http://www.samlogic.net/articles/32-64-bit-windows-folder-x86-syswow64.htm)? In Microsoft land, 64-bit things go in **System32**.

Answer (score 9):

`r27`: revision 27

`82525`: build 82525

`Jul 4 2010, 07:43:08`: when your python binary was built

`MSC v.1500`: compiled with 64w-bit VC++ 2008

`win32`: you are using windows

[It has also been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2676763/what-version-of-visual-studio-is-python-on-my-computer-compiled-with).

Comment: Thanks although I wouldn't have known to search for that other question - I only searched for "python version line"