# Why python is showing win32 instead of win64?

Tags: python

I have installed python 2.7 on windows 64 bit. But python is telling me that it is installed on windows 32 bit. See image below.

[image]

Where as my system is 64 bit as shown in the image below.
[image]

Comment: no the version of python is 64 bit. see first image.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3411079/why-does-the-python-2-7-amd-64-installer-seem-to-run-python-in-32-bit-mode

Comment: Thank you @StepanTsymbal

Comment: `win32` is an architecture not a bitness. You will see messages issued by 64-bit executable that talk about `win32`. This is normal.

Comment: @BoarGules: according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17757819/what-does-the-python-version-line-mean), `win32` just seems to be a misleading name for "Windows platform". It's not an architecture in the sense of a particular CPU...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the Python version line mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17757819/what-does-the-python-version-line-mean)

Comment: @MrFuppes It is a software architecture in the sense that it was devised to set `win32` apart from its predecessor 16-bit OS. That involved changing the signatures of every function in the huge Windows API to accept 32-bit instead of 16-bit quantities. Whether that counts as a different architecture is a matter of opinion, but my main point stands. `win32` in messages has nothing to do with the bitness of the Python executable or the DLLs that it calls. 64-bit executables still complain when asked to call 32-bit DLLs, and though the messages vary, they may still say *not a valid `win32` file*.

Comment: @BoarGules - thanks for the clarification. "*win32 in messages has nothing to do with the bitness of the Python executable or the DLLs that it calls*" - what about the Windows side? If `win32` appears only for historical reasons, I would still call this misleading to people seeing this the first time? I mean, Windows is not limited to 32bit addresses anymore