# Python 64 bit? What does "on win32" mean?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Team,

I am hiring you all back on. I have a question about the banner that is displayed directly after typing the word 'python'. This banner appears when activating the interactive shell.

Below one can see the banner in my current installation. I noticed that towards the end of the line there are the words, `on win32`. This is before the 'Type "help",...' line. Does this "on win32" mean that Python is running on a 32 bit operating system? I checked the control panel of my Windows installation and saw that the operating system is 64bit. I just installed a 64bit installation of Python so I am fairly sure that the Python application is 64 bit.

```
Python 2.7.14 (v2.7.14:84471935ed, Sep 16 2017, 20:25:58) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AM
D64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Also, I executed the following command and this apparently means that I am running a 64 bit version of Python. Please see the code as follows:

```
>>> import platform
>>> platform.architecture()
('64bit', 'WindowsPE')
```

Comment: Unsure if this should be marked a dupe, but take a look at the answer (including the comments) for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17757819/what-does-the-python-version-line-mean

Comment: Yeah I guess that explains the problem. I am unsure why they would have "win32" in the 64 bit version of Python though. Or why they compiled the 64bit version of Python for a 32 bit architecture.

Comment: i have windows10 64bit and 'on win32' is still there

Comment: What version of Python?

Comment: This is a dupe, but I don't think the recommended source actually gets to the heart of this question.  A better link would be:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17757819/ .