# "error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat" when installing Fabric (Python library) on Windows

Tags: python, windows, fabric

I tried installing [Fabric](http://fabfile.org/) in my Windows 7 64-bit machine and all I got was this lousy error message:

> building 'Crypto.Random.OSRNG.winrandom' extension
>
> warning: GMP or MPIR library not found; Not building
>   Crypto.PublicKey._fastmath.
>
> error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

None of the answers in this similar question error: [Unable to find vcvarsall.bat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817869/error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat)  worked for me. What to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the root cause is as described [here](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.8/installation.html):

> Some Windows users whose Python is 64-bit have found that the PyCrypto
>   dependency winrandom may not install properly, leading to
>   ImportErrors. In this scenario, you’ll probably need to compile
>   winrandom yourself via e.g. MS Visual Studio. See #194 for info.

I've been able to resolve the issue by downloading and installing a PyCrypto binary from [Michael Foord's website](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/modules.shtml#pycrypto) and then re-installing Fabric. Many thanks Michael!

Comment: I am seeing this issue with Python3.4 version. The PyCrypto binaries on Michael Foord's website are specific to Python 2.6. Any suggestions, please let me know.

Comment: @DevPat The binaries on Michael Foord's website also extend to Python v2.7, v3.2 and v3.3 (but not v3.4). Maybe v3.3 binaries will work for you? http://www.voidspace.org.uk/downloads/pycrypto26/pycrypto-2.6.win32-py3.3.exe

Comment: I keep getting the same error. I have downgraded my Python version to v3.3. I also ran VC++ 2010 installation as suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2676763/what-version-of-visual-studio-is-python-on-my-computer-compiled-with/2676904#2676904) to see if that fixes the issue. Still no luck.  Please suggest if there is any other thing that I need to do/try.