# Building a Python C++ extension

Tags: python, c++

I'd like to build a C++ extension for Python. I took a simple C file from a tutorial and wrote the setup.py file. But when I run the command:

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

I get the following error:

```
error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
```

This file is located in "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\vc\vcvarsall.bat" but even when I run it and set all environment variables, python.exe still tries to find it. I added this path to the PATH but it didn't solve the issue. I know this problem has been reported several times on Stack Overflow, but I haven't found any working solution.

Comment: you need python dev headers from microsoft

Comment: First check you have the right version of Visual Studio for your version of python  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2676763/what-version-of-visual-studio-is-python-on-my-computer-compiled-with.

Comment: I have Visual Studio 13 and the version of Python is 3.5.1.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the latest version of python27
Download Microsoft visual compiler for python 2.7

In your setup script, write ***from setuptools import setup, Extension*** instead of ***from distutils.core import setup, Extension***

refer to 
https://github.com/cython/cython/wiki/CythonExtensionsOnWindows for more information