# Steps for compiling Python with a non-standard MSC version

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio, python-2.7, visual-studio-2013

I need to get a version of 32-bit Python compilied with MSC v.1800, which [indicates Visual C++ 2013 (12.0))](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2676904/1461850).

It seems that Microsoft's standard compiler, [Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python 2.7](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44266&751be11f-ede8-5a0c-058c-2ee190a24fa6=True&e6b34bbe-475b-1abd-2c51-b5034bcdd6d2=True&fa43d42b-25b5-4a42-fe9b-1634f450f5ee=True), results in MSC v. 1500, which [indicates Visual C++ 2008  (9.0)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2676904/1461850). The official installer seems to have used this version.

**What is the standard way to install `Python 2.7.11[MSC v1800 32 bit (Intel)]` on Windows 7?**

My plan at the moment is:

1. Download source from [Python.org](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2711/)
2. Download MS Visual Studio 2013 Express from [Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=44914)
3. Compile using MS VS tools

However, I'm wondering if there is a more straight-forward way?

Comment: This looks like the most basic and standard way to me, not sure what would be more straight forward. But if there is one I'd be happy to learn as well. But again, odds are this is the most straight forward way there is.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download source from [Python.org](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2711/)
2. Download MS Visual Studio 2013 Express from [Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=44914)
3. Install [Subversion](http://subversion.apache.org/) and ensure that it is in PATH
4. Open PythonVersion/PCBuild/PCBuild.proj in MS Visual studio - accept suggestion to retarget files to VS2013
5. Run `build.bat -e` in the PCBuild directory of Python source